# Simulating Key Press in C#

Tags: c#, escaping, key, simulate

So I want to make my program automatically simulate a key press after a timer stops. I have the timer and every setup already I just need to somehow simulate a key press. After a download message pops up on a web browser in the application I just want the program to simulate as "ESC" key press to exit out of the download message popup. How would I simulate the key press?

Answer (score 6):

I would use the SendKeys class, documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

To send an 'Esc' keypush, for example, you would write:

```
SendKeys.Send("{ESC}");
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use the [Windows Input Simulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/) as it is more reliable than `Sendkeys`.

Comment: I have installed that package using nuget in my project. And I have also added using system.windows.input; on top of my code. but when i use this                                    InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);
it says, windowsinputSimulator does not contain definiton of simulate key press. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What platform are you using? WinForms?

Comment: I am using WPF C#. I have a file called MainWindow.xaml.cs and yes I am using windows forms too inside.

Comment: I just looked at my project where I used this and the import statement was `using WindowsInput;` - not `using system.windows.input;`

Comment: If anybody is interested,  it works perfect with Unity3D :)

Answer (score -2):

on the client side, use the jQuery.trigger command